# How to determine if Linux OS is on virtual hardware or physical hardware?

Tags: linux, virtualization

From a Linux OS, is there a way to determine if the OS is running as a guest OS on a virtualized VMware environment as opposed to running directly on non-virtualized/bare metal/physical host?  In my case it is either VMware or not, but I am also interested the more general question of whether the OS is on physical hardware or virtualized hardware of any sort.

Comment: Use the "virt-what" command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VMware:

```
# dmidecode --string system-product-name
VMware Virtual Platform
```

In Virtualbox same command outputs `VirtualBox`

Answer (score 2):

On newer systems, the command "lscpu" give's you the information you need, inclusive which hypervisor the VM is running on.

Comment: This seems to work for newer versions showing the "Hypervisor vendor:" entry when a hypervisor is present, but doesn't work for older versions that don't have lscpu such as RHEL 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the output of the following:

- virt-what
- cat /proc/cpuinfo
- dmidecode
- lspci
- lshw
- hwinfo

Any of these will print various things that should point to if and what virtualisation-platform is being used.